# Which is the value of a "big" character hexadecimal constant in C?

Tags: c, char, integer, c99, c11

Suppose that we write in C the following character constant:

```
  '\xFFFFAA'
```

Which is its numerical value?

The standard **C99** says:

- Character constants have type `int`.
- Hexadecimal character constants can be represented as an `unsigned char`.
- The value of a basic character constant is non-negative.
- The value of any character constant fits in the range of `char`.

Besides:

- The range of values of `signed char` is contained in the range of values of `int`.
- The size (in bits) of `char`, `unsigned char` and `signed char` are the same: 1 byte.
- The size of a byte is given by `CHAR_BIT`, whose value is at least 8.

Let's suppose that we have the typical situation with `CHAR_BIT == 8`.
Also, let's suppose that `char` is `signed char` for us.

By following the rules: the constant '\xFFFFAA' has type `int`, but its value *can be represented* in an `unsigned char`, althoug its **real value** fits in a `char`.
From these rules, an example as '\xFF' would give us:

```
  (int)(char)(unsigned char)'\xFF' == -1
```

The 1st cast `unsigned char` comes from the **"can be represented as unsigned char"** requirement.
The 2nd cast `char` comes from the **"the value fits in a char"** requirement.
The 3rd cast `int`  comes from the **"has type int"** requirement.

However, the constant `'\xFFFFAA'` is too big, and cannot be "represented" as `unsigned int`.
Wich is its value?

I think that the value is the resulting of `(char)(0xFFFFAA % 256)` since the standard says, more or less, the following:

- For unsigned integer types, if a value is bigger that the maximum *M* that can be represented by the type, the value is the obtained after taking the remainder modulo *M*.

Am I right with this conclusion?

**EDIT** I have convinced by **@KeithThompson**: He says that, according to the standards, a big hexadecimal character constant is a constraint violation.
So, I will accept that answer.

**However:** For example, with GCC 4.8, MinGW, the compiler triggers a **warning** message, and the program compiles following the behaviour I have described. Thus, it was considered valid a constant like '\x100020' and its value was 0x20.

Comment: You wrote `'xFFFFAA'`. Did you mean `'\xFFFFAA'`?

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, it was a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Pedantic, I know, but `char` is not ALWAYS 8-bits, even if that is by far the most common size.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Observe that I said: "Let's suppose the **typical** situation of ... 8 bits". The intent is to be concrete in the example, to make the question clear.

Comment: A constraint violation requires a diagnostic. The standard doesn't say that the implementation can't also compile your program successfully, serve you breakfast in bed, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C standard defines the syntax and semantics in section 6.4.4.4. I'll cite the [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) draft of the C11 standard.

Paragraph 6:

> The hexadecimal digits that follow the backslash and the letter **x** in a
>   hexadecimal escape sequence are taken to be part of the construction
>   of a single character for an integer character constant or of a single
>   wide character for a wide character constant. The numerical value of
>   the hexadecimal integer so formed specifies the value of the desired
>   character or wide character.

Paragraph 9:

> **Constraints**
>
> The value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence shall be in the
>   range of representable values for the corresponding type:

followed by a table saying that with no prefix, the "corresponding type" is `unsigned char`.

So, assuming that `0xFFFFAA` is outside the representable range for type `unsigned char`, the character constant `'\xFFFFAA'` is a constraint violation, requiring a compile-time diagnostic. A compiler is free to reject your source file altogether.

If your compiler doesn't at least warn you about this, it's failing to conform to the C standard.

Yes, the standard does say that unsigned types have modular (wraparound) semantics, but that only applies to arithmetic expressions and some conversions, not to the meanings of constants.

(If `CHAR_BIT >= 24` on your system, it's perfectly valid, but that's rare; usually `CHAR_BIT == 8`.)

If a compiler chooses to issue a mere warning and then continue to compile your source, the behavior is undefined (simply because the standard doesn't define the behavior).

On the other hand, if you had actually meant `'xFFFFAA'`, that's not interpreted as hexadecimal. (I see it was merely a typo, and the question has been edited to correct it, but I'm going to leave this here anyway.) Its value is implementation-defined, as described in paragraph 10:

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g.,
>   **'ab'**), ..., is implementation-defined.

Character constants containing more than one character are a nearly useless language feature, used by accident more often than they're used intentionally.

Comment: I meant '\xFFFFAA' only. I understand the situations like 'ab'.

Comment: @pabol1977, hexadecimal escape sequence is just a form to represent an integer character constant. So the rule of integer character constant apples.

Comment: @EricZ: But the rule violated by `'\xFFFFAA'` is specific to hexadecimal (and octal) character constants.

Comment: @Keith, I agree. And the solution is well-defined in the semantics part, as a general one. Isn't it?

Comment: @EricZ: The rules for character constants and integer constants are the same after an integer value has been decided for `'\xFFFFAA'`. But before this moment, what happens? For example, you can have `'\xFF' == -1` in some cases. On the other hand, '\xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF' is still an hexadecimal character constant (becase there are no limits for the number of hexadecimal digits there), but the "value" is out of the range of `unsigned char`. After that, the value has to fit in a `char`, and finally is promoted to type `int`.

Comment: @EricZ: I don't know what you mean by "the solution is well-defined". Given `CHAR_BIT < 24`, a diagnostic for `'\xFFFFAA'` is mandatory, and the semantics are undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the value of `\xFFFFAA` should be representable by `unsigned char`.

**6.4.4.4 9 Constraints**

> The value of an octal or hexadecimal escape sequence shall be in the
>   range of representable values for the type unsigned char for an
>   integer character constant.

But C99 also says,

**6.4.4.4 10 Semantics**

> The value of an integer character constant containing more than one
>   character (e.g., 'ab'), or containing a character or escape sequence
>   that does not map to a single-byte execution character, is
>   implementation-defined.

So the resulting value should be in the range of unsigned char([0, 255], if CHAR_BIT == 8). But as to which one, it depends on the compiler, architecture, etc.

Comment: More than that, since it violates a constraint (unless `CHAR_BIT >= 24`), a compiler is permitted to reject it altogether.

Comment: @Keith, C99 says the value should be presentable in `unsigned char`. It's just a matter of how compilers interpret this integer literal. It can produce a compile-time warning as you said. Or it can just use an "implementation-defined" value that falls in the range of `unsigned char`, not necessary giving out a warning. That's totally legal even if `CHAR_BIT=8`.

Comment: No, [N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) 6.4.4.4p9 is a *constraint*, which requires a compile-time diagnostic according to 5.1.1.3p1. Once it issues the diagnostic, it can do anything it likes; the standard no longer has anything to say about it.

Comment: `Of course, an implementation is free to produce any number of diagnostics as long as a valid program is still correctly translated.` I think `any number` can be interpreted as an implementation-defined manner, and can be zero. What do you think?

Comment: I think that if `CHAR_BIT < 24`, a diagnostic for `'\xxFFFFAA'` is mandatory, as you'll see if you read the citations I pointed you to. A compiler that doesn't issue a diagnostic is non-conforming. Compilers are free to issue additional diagnostics (warnings), but that's not relevant to this case.

Comment: "I think any number can be interpreted" -- You're talking about how to interpret your own words? That "of course" is not language from the standard; the standard says something quite different, namely that a diagnostic -- that is, at least one -- is required.